# How to generate a bottom to top list view of react native

Tags: listview, react-native

I need a list view that from bottom to top, like all of social contact Apps do.

From my perspective, in iOS we can turn the UITableView down and rebuild the cell

layout. But in react native, I don't clearly know what to do, is there any library

to do this? Or any other solution.

Please help me, this makes me crazy!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of choice. You can use [official `ListView` component](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content),  [`TableView` component](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content) plugin or search what you like in [react.part](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what the official ListView component is? I didn't check it in the doc. Native UITableView component must be useful, but I don't wanna choose this way. Can you give some more details? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Prometheus, it's base on `UIScrollView`, you can check more detail in [`ListView`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js) and [`ScrollView`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js)

Comment: This question is still bother me, but thank you so much.